Scaling issue with cylinder created from blender scaled using three js
I have an OBJ file created using Blender. I need to scale it using Three.js. The scaling works well for cube-like objects, but cylinder-type objects are not scaling correctly. Please correct this."
To solve the cylinder issue

Could you show some code, codepen or something?
